# Unable to retrieve job history beyond 2 months in BigQuery Web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to repeat a load job for a table I created 3 months ago, but I am only able to see 2 months of job history in BigQuery browser UI. I would like the table schema used in that specific load job.

Is there any way to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Jobs.list` in the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list):

> Lists all jobs that you started in the specified project. Job
>   information **is available for a six month period** after creation

You could also use the cli tool:

```
bq ls --jobs --all
```

Or, you could use [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) too.

Comment: bq ls --jobs --all

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.